# Storing and using data read in line by line

Tags: java

If I have a file to read[Sequentially] from that contains two teams and their scores on each line such as:

Panthers  3 Cavaliers    5

Rockets  4   Titans  9

Anteaters 8   Yahoos 6

Panthers  10 Titans 3

Yahoos 4  Rockets 7

I need to think of a way to keep track of each team and its wins and losses and print them out to a new file. Such as:

TEAM       WINS     LOSSES

Panthers 1 1

Rockets 0 2

The problem that im facing is that I do not know how to store the name of the teams in such a way that i will be able to add the wins or losses to that team as the PrintWriter reads in the data. Any input would be appreciated along with an explanation.. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;
public class SoccerLeague
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
    {
        File inputFile= new File("SoccerNotSorted.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
        if(!inputFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        File outputFile= new File("SoccerSort.txt");
        PrintWriter output= new PrintWriter(outputFile);
        if (!outputFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("output file not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while(input.hasNext())//This is where i attempted to solve the prob.
        {

            //String team1 = input.next();
            //int score1 = input.nextInt();
            //String team2= input.next();
            //int score2=input.nextInt();
            //int wins=0;
            //if(score1>score2)
            //{
            //  output.println(team1+"wins against"+team2);
            //} 
            //else()



        }
        input.close();
        output.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to store a list of teams somewhere. You can't do this in real-time. It's something you do by getting your data, processing it, and then outputting.

Comment: Create a class for each Team with a String for name, an int for wins and an int for losses. Create an `ArrayList<Team>` and update it as you read from the file.

Comment: So far, after reading the suggestions I have tried to implement an array to store the names of teams without making duplicates and the problem I keep facing is that since each line contains not only the name of the teams but also the score in the format shown above this throws off my loop for capturing the team name.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to have a String associated with another piece of data, e.g. the running total of wins/loses. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Team> allTeams = new ArrayList<Team>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    // "Panthers 3 Cavaliers 5", for example
    String teamString = scanner.nextLine();
    String[4] teamComponents = teamString.split(" ");
    Team team1 = new Team();
    team1.setName(teamComponents[0]); // sets team1 name to Panthers
    team1.setScore(Integer.valueOf(teamComponents[1]); // sets team1 score to 3
    Team team2 = new Team();
    team2.setName(teamComponents[2]); // sets team2 name to Cavaliers
    team2.setScore(Integer.valueOf(teamComponents[3]); // sets team2 score to 5
    allTeams.add(team1);
    allTeams.add(team2); // now you can access all of the Team objects created in the while loop outside of the loop, 
    // since the List was instantiated before iterating through all of the lines in your input file
}
```

By the end of the loop your list should have 10 Team objects. 
Remember that the names team1 and team2 are arbitrary and are only important inside the loop - the List object outside of the loop knows nothing about the variable names inside the loop.